# How to deploy ASP.NET Web App into the world wide web (Internet)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, ip-address

I have a ASP.Net Web App that is ready for deployment. At the moment I have used the IIS (Internet Information Services) to deploy the whole app and so far it is pretty good despite some errors like CSS is not running and an error in connecting to the database (.mdf file).
However, my question is how can I deploy it in public by using its IP Address? I have tried to google it and can't find a good tutorials/guides. It can be a book, or some blog/journals or something else.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This question probably better belongs on serverfault.

You need to have your router configured to [forward port 80](http://portforward.com/) to the internal IP address of the server hosting IIS with the website (assuming it is hosted on port 80).  Then you should be able to type in your [network's public IP address](http://www.whatismyip.com/) to access the website.  If you have a domain name setup, you can point that to your public IP and set the host header of the IIS website to that IP.  You can also setup a [DynDNS account](http://www.dyndns.com/) for a free simple domain name (such as `Sammm.dyndns.com`) that can be kept updated with software on the server if your IP address is not static.